# How to remove MenuStrip submenu margins?

Tags: c#, menustrip

Do you know how to remove margin (probably the one for image and check box on the left and right) of the submenu in MenuStri? In [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229638.aspx) there is explained how to remove it from context menus. It is written that I should do it the same way in MenuStrip but MenuStrip do not have ShowImageMargin nor ShowCheckMargin. Maybe I'm missing something. Can you help?

Comment: Are you not using images in your menustrip or do you want to display the margin only if the submenu contains a check or image?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Very similar, but instead of using "ContextMenuStrip" (which is used in your [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229638.aspx)), you have to use "**ToolStripDropDownMenu**". This way:

```
((ToolStripDropDownMenu)noMargins.DropDown).ShowImageMargin = false;
```

For example, if you want to remove all image margins from your menubar called "menuStrip1", add this code to your form initialization routine:

```
// Removing image margins (space for icons on left) from menubar items:
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem menuItem in menuStrip1.Items)
    ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)menuItem.DropDown).ShowImageMargin = false;
```