# How to hide menu image section

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I hide selected area in sub menu item ?
please refer attached image .. [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove MenuStrip submenu margins?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/853873/1577396)

Answer (score 0):

Late Answer:

Use The Method **ShowImageMargin()** for Hiding ContexMenu Strip on Righ click..
& Please select subitems as another ContexMenuStrip.

```
    ContextMenuStrip1.ShowImageMargin = true;
```

this Hides the area you marked.